# Redux-form calling submit outside form component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm building an application with dynamic forms (redux-form). I would like when user click on submit button to print values. Note that my submit button is placed in my application header (outside the form). To achieve this, I'm following this [tutorial](http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/examples/remoteSubmit) from Redux-form. When I press the "Save" button, I got this error in my console : `(0 , _reduxForm.submit) is not a function(…)`.

My code :

**Submit component**

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {submit} from 'redux-form'

const RemoteSubmitButton = ({dispatch}) =>
   // How to get 'form' prop here ?
  <button type="submit" onClick={() => dispatch( submit() ) }>Save</button>
export default connect()(RemoteSubmitButton)
```

**Main component**

```
// Import librairies
import Submit from 'submitBtn'
export default class extends Component {
    ...
    render(){
         return (
            // html code
            <Submit form="newuser" /> // form prop gonna be dynamic
        )
    }
}
```

**submit.js**

```
import {SubmissionError} from 'redux-form'

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

function submit(values) {
  return sleep(1000) // simulate server latency
    .then(() => {
      window.alert(`You submitted:\n\n${JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}`)
    })
}

export default submit
```

**new.js (New User)**

```
//Import librairies
import submit from 'submit'

class UserForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const {error, resetForm, handleSubmit} = this.props

    return (<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
             <!-- Generate dynamic fields -->
            </form>)
  }
}

let FormWrapper = reduxForm({form: 'newuser', onSubmit: submit})(UserForm)

const selector = formValueSelector('newuser') // <-- same as form name
FormWrapper = connect(state => state.form)(FormWrapper)
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? or What can I do to make it work please ?

Comment: Can you confirm what version of `redux-form` you are using? What you are doing certainly seems correct.

Comment: @Ashley'CptLemming'Wilson I use v6.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `submit` action was added in `v6.2.0` according to the [release notes](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases/tag/v6.2.0).

You need to upgrade your version of `redux-form` in order for this to work.

**Edit:**

In order to submit the form, you need to use the `form` prop in your `RemoteSubmitButton` component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {submit} from 'redux-form'

const RemoteSubmitButton = ({ dispatch, form }) =>  // Destructure the props here
  <button type="submit" onClick={() => dispatch( submit(form) ) }>Save</button>
export default connect()(RemoteSubmitButton)
```

Comment: I've upgraded the lib with no luck. When I specify to `form` an `id` and pass its value to submit button as form props it works. But I can do that in my case because I have many forms that use the same button.

Comment: I'm not too sure I follow. Are you saying you want a single submit button that can be used for multiple forms?

Comment: Exacty, but its not really important... I've added a prop to `<Submit form='myForm' />` but I don't know how can I get its value from the body of submit component (Please see my updated code).

Comment: I've updated my answer with the `form` prop passed to the `submit` action. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Can we send paramater on submit action ?